# Can language reveal how we think?

Tags: psycholinguistics, cognitive-linguistics, neurolinguistics

I have just started lightly reading about consciousness and, in trying to think about what it is, I couldn't help but notice how simply thinking about the pronoun "I" could shed quite a bit of light on what humans make of the concept. My question is, are there other instances of this (i.e., language shedding light on how humans make sense of a particular concept)? Please note that I am not asking about whether language shapes human thinking. Instead, I am asking the converse: are there instances where we can use language to reveal something about a concept (such as consciousness) or, more accurately, to reveal how humans have come to think about a concept? Is there a term for this in linguistics?

Comment: Could you, please, explain, from your point of view, _what light_ does simply thinking about the pronoun "I" could shed on what humans make of the concept? What do you mean? To suggest other instances of _this_ we've got to know at least  something about what you call “this”.

Comment: For sure. Sorry for the lack of clarity. I have got another instance pertaining to the concept of "self" that might make it clearer. From the little reading about the "self" that I have done, it seems an important question (probably the most fundamental to the concept) is: "how does a human recognise themself as an entity separate to others"? The scaffolding for the answer, I think, lies (again) in looking at such pronouns as "I", "you", "we", etc... It seems to me that these, at different instances, define boundaries within which we see a self.

Comment: So, in this case, the pronouns served as a guide to get closer to the answer of how it is that humans perceive a self (an entity separate to others). In the case where it is "I", the self that is being perceived is the self that is doing the perceiving. In the case that it is "you", the subject of the perception is separate from the perceiver. And there is yet another case for "we". These, I think, "shed light" on either (1) the concept of self or (2) reveal how humans have come to think about the concept of self. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Note that “I” is a _pronoun_ which means “instead of a noun” with the function to point to the speaker without naming them. By «speaker» I mean the participant of a conversation who is talking at this moment. When I'm talking to you “I” means “Yellow Sky”, next moment when you're talking to me “I” means “Then-Brief-864”, the word “I” constantly changes its referent, its essence and purpose of existence is to mean _everything possible_. When we talk, each of us is “I”, how can this reveal the way humans perceive a self, if we, two different selves, use one and the same word to call oneself?

Comment: Also, since “I” means “the speaker” and “you” means “the listener”, one can even refer to oneself not as “I”, but also as “you”, it is this point which is quite interesting in understanding one's self. When you say to yourself, “You can do it!”, who is the speaker and who is the listener in this situation? ;-) On one hand, everybody in the world is “I” which looks like everybody is the same as everybody else, but on the other hand, a person can talk to oneself, being now “I”, now “you”. My point is that ‘simply thinking’ about such desemantized words as pronouns can reveal little about “self”.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

This is implicit in the term "concept". Concepts are "things" viewed as a unit of sorts, and assigned a label (word, or more properly morpheme). There are diverse objects that we call "hammer", "cloud", "flower" which we see as being the same in some way, and we ignore the differences as being unimportant. This applies to action concepts like "throw" and "cook", attribute concepts like "blue" and "tall", and so on.

The universe does not have a pre-cooked inventory of concepts, humans make them up in our languages based on one perceptible property versus another. Saami languages have very many words for reindeer, we just have "reindeer". The relationship between a particular concept (embodied as a word) and the things that it refers to thus reflects an optional perceptual "sameness" where you focus on one thing rather than another as the basis for classifying. This leads to the situation where a glass lizard is classified as a kind of snake in some languages (it *looks* like a snake).

The practical problem with using language as evidence for how we "see" the universe is that it is very hard to empirically distinguish accidental facts of existence from deliberate viewpoint-based distinctions. The reason why English has such an impoverished reindeer vocabulary is that we have an impoverished experience of the diversity of reindeers. However, we have a well-nourished vocabulary for sub-classifying dogs compared to that found in other languages. Our vocabulary for legumes is very poor compared to that of Hindi, which is not the result of "world view", it is the result of "how the world is, locally", which then may have some bearing on world view.

IMO the clearest demonstration of a real connection between world view and language is kinship terminology. In English, the male siblings of your parents are called "uncle" and the females are called "aunt". In numerous other languages, for example Bantu languages of East Africa, the male siblings of your father are also your "father", and the female sibling of your mother are your "mother" – their kinship system is based on a "same sex" vs. "different sex" parameter, which reflects viewpoint as reflected both in language and social rules.

Comment: Quite a few languages have different words for your father's uncle v. your mother's uncle (and same with aunt).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much!